# SQL Developer code completion only current schema

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, code-completion

Is there a way to setup code completion in SQL Developer so I only can see my objects or objects from the current schema?
My problem is that I have many schemas with the same table names.

Today it looks like this when I do code completion:
[image]

As you can see only the first table is from my schema.
When I press the three dots in the popup it looks like this:
[image]
It would be nice if I could get the last popup on the first code completion. Is this possible?

Regards
Håkan

Comment: Just include your schema prefix in your query.

Comment: What version are you running? The local schema objects should be listed first...